# Discord.js v13 delete message after a certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, promise, discord.js

Up to discord.js v12, my bot would delete messages it posted like this :

```js
message.reply("text")
  .then(msg => {
    message.delete()
    msg.delete({timeout: 5000})    //amount of time I want it to wait in milliseconds
  })
  .catch()
```

However, now that I updated discord.js modules to v13, the message is deleted instantly.

Is there a new method to do that, or am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: _"Is there a new method to do that"_ - The documentation of v13 will tell you that.

Comment: There's even a ["Breaking changes"](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#before-you-start) section

Comment: I failed to see it even though I wandered in the documentation for quite some time... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that, as stated in the documentation [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#message-delete), `msg.delete()` does not accept options anymore, meaning the correct code is now this :

```js
message.reply("text")
  .then(repliedMessage => {
    setTimeout(() => repliedMessage.delete(), 5000);
  });
  .catch();
```